# How can I create default/global launch configurations for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep setting up the same *launch.json* file per project. But I would like to change the default one so it's already got the launch targets configured.

Can I change the default one, or is it possible to create a user one? I'm using it on Mac OS X.

Comment: As far as I know, initial configuration settings for launch.json are kept in extension (in package.json or somewhere else)  and generated automatically when you create project, you can change it manually but all changes will lost after upgrading extension.

Comment: ok no worries not a big deal - would be great to have a template project option though because for every project I pretty much copy and paste about 10 files.

Comment: 'launch.json' is generated by a template provided by the debugger that you have selected for the project. It is not tied to package.json at all since vscode supports more than javascript.

Comment: @Gorkem Ercan: Isn't it always a JSON file, JavaScript or not?

Comment: Correct, regardless of the language it is launch.json. Depending on the language/debugger the properties of configuration may change

Comment: related: [How can I set a default tasks.json file for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76141850/11107541)