# How do I set the default launch.json and tasks.json for debugging my C/C++ applications in VS Code

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have set up my launch.jason and tasks.json files for VS Code, and can debug my applications using that. The problem is whenever I create a new application, I have to find the files from one of my old apps and copy paste them to the new application folder. And if I delete these .json files, I have no option but to rewrite them again which is pretty inconvenient.

Is there a way to set these files as the default ones for all C/C++ projects? So whenever I create a new project, VS Code automatically loads these files?

Comment: Not really, no. You could just use a proper build system like cmake or meson instead then you can use the relevant plugins which will auto configure vscode

Comment: if you use VS you have to recreate a solution file for each new project

Comment: this is a duplicate of two questions: for tasks, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76141850/11107541. for launch, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43096290/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have never done this myself, the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) seem to suggest that you can have launch setting which are scoped outside of your project:

> VS Code keeps debugging configuration information in a launch.json file located in a .vscode folder in your workspace (project root folder) or in your [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) or [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-launch-configurations).

[The docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) also seem to suggest that VS Code might have a mechanism for wider scoped tasks through a "[Task Provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider)":

> Workspace or folder specific tasks are configured from the `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder for a workspace.
>
> Extensions can also contribute tasks using a [Task Provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider), and these contributed tasks can add workspace-specific configurations defined in the `tasks.json` file.

I realise an answer from someone who has actually used these features would be preferable, but I thought I'd point them out nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this and try both suggestions.