# How can I add global properties for C++ files in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Now, for using VS Code in my Mac M1, I have to basically have to keep a .vscode folder in every directory where I run my code on. Which contains the `c_cpp_properties.json`, `tasks.json`, and `settings.json` files. Is there any way to make sure that every C++ file in my Laptop follows a specific configuration if there are no local configuration files overwriting them? Even a solution which inculcates this behaviour in subdirectories is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `c_cpp_properties.json`, I'm pretty sure there's no such thing as a global version of that file. But if all you want is a default configuration and not to actually get the configurations defined in a "global `c_cpp_properties.json` file", you can just use the `C_Cpp.default.*` settings in your user [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

For launch.json, see [How can I create default/global launch configurations for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43096290/11107541). TL;DR use the `"launch"` property of your user settings.json.

For tasks.json, see [How can I set a default tasks.json file for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76141850/11107541). TL;DR [there's no such thing at the time of this writing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5779#issuecomment-214620412).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The C_Cpp.default advice solved my issue.